# Can't access System.Console in Monogame app C#

Tags: c#, monogame

I cloned a Monogame app which I am testing out. I have included using `System;` at the top of my file. Visual Studio shows that it's not being used. When I try to type `Console.WriteLine("");` in my code, or even `System.Console.WriteLine("");` (which shouldn't even require a using directive) it's simply not recognized.

[image]

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I'm aware that currently my app is not a Console app since it's a game. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, although I would think I would still be able to using `System.Console`, even if there wasn't a console to print it to...

(This brings up a side note, which is that I can't seem to add a console window to my program, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39011035/8887398. The option just simply isn't there. See picture below.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your app is a MonoGame app has nothing to do with the problem you're encountering. It's because your app is a UWP app (this wasn't mentioned in your post, but I guessed so based on the screenshot). There is no System.Console in UWP apps.

For more info see:

[How to use System.Console in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089694/how-to-use-system-console-in-uwp)

Comment: Okay. I was unaware that it was a UWP app, so I didn't know to mention it. I have gotten print statements to work only when debugging, with the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("someString"); command. Still haven't figured out a way to print when not debugging or pop up console window, but this is at least something.

Comment: You may want to switch to a "standard" C# implementation for log files. There are many examples outh there and might come in handy instead of WriteLine